# Retrofit 2 is not making calls

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've setup retrofit 2.1 and it is not making calls to my api at all. I just setup a lamp stack and made my ip publicly accessible. I'm trying to send information via a POST to my php script which would add data to my db. For some reason, retrofit will not make the call to my api... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
@POST("/sendInformation.php")
Call<JSONObject> sendUserInfo(@Body JSONObject userViewModel);



OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.d(TAG, message));
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        client.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client.build())
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        UserInformationService userService = retrofit.create(UserInformationService.class);


        Call<JSONObject> call = userService.sendUserInfo(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I tried to add logging but it won't make the call so I can't even see the logging. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: The BASE_URL I'm using is my public IP. I just forwarded my ports so it's accessible. I tried doing a POST on hurl.it and it works fine. It's only retrofit not working. I've also tried this with an asyncTask and httpURLConnection and it also works. I must be missing something really minor...

Comment: You need to call one of the blocking or non-blocking methods on the call object.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM like enqueue?

Answer (score 3):

```
Call<JSONObject> call = userService.sendUserInfo(jsonObject);
```

This line is not enough. The `Call<T>` object represents an 'intent' of a call rather than the operation itself, and you need to execute it by calling one of two methods on the object: **execute** and **enqueue**.

**Execute** works in a blocking manner and will **return** your `JSONObject` through the `response.getBody()` method:

```
Response<JSONObject> response = call.execute();
```

**Enqueue** works asynchronously and will provide your `JSONObject` through the `callback` object - if call is successful, `onResponse` method will be called with your `response` as a call parameter.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: see my edit. I was already calling it I just forgot to put it in my original question. It's been edited. I should also mention I don't want to get data back from this post. It is entirely for sending data to be stored in a DB.

Comment: Ended up figuring it out. Apparently Retrofit 2 doesn't play nicely with JsonObjects as request bodies. You're able to send off a POJO and it will become a JSON object, but you cannot use JSONOject. :)

Comment: maybe use JsonObject from gson with GsonConverterFactory instead or just use POJO if your json simple enough

Comment: The POJO becomes a JSONObject by the use of converter (Jackson converter in your case). It's up to the converter how it deals with JSONObjects as request bodies. A suggestion: use `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY` log level to see everything related to retrofit requests and responses in your logcat.

Comment: You need to configure Gson serializer for your responses. Check their documentation.